# Regex expression excluding "-" tag

Tags: python, regex

Hi right now my regex expression is working as intended. However i wish to specifically exclude  items such as 
how do i update my regex such that it would exclude entries with "-\d*"/ negative quantity? ?

https://regex101.com/r/4EUzLo/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
'\d+\s*([a-zA-Z].*\w)\s+\d.*'
```

The `'\d+` will only match the positive quantities, and with less steps.

Now, just extract the info from the capture group.

<kbd>[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UylZqb/1)</kbd>

Comment: sorry to trouble you. I have updated the regex test string! Can you help again?

Comment: DONE I SOLVED ALREADY! THANKS FOR YOUR HELP SIR